# what is the way to solve this issue

Tags: r

this code in R language
i am having this error: Error in seq.int(2, length(xj), 2) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In seq.int(a, b, length.out = n + 1) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
can you help me to solve it , thank you

```
  b=1
  a=0
  n <- c(2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512)
  f <- function(x) {
    return(x^3/2)
  }
h <- (b - a) / n
xj <- seq.int(a, b, length.out = n + 1)
xj <- xj[-1]
xj <- xj[-length(xj)]
approx <- (h / 3) * (f(a) + 2 * sum(f(xj[seq.int(2, length(xj), 2)])) + 4 * sum(f(xj[seq.int(1, length(xj), 2)])) + f(b))
  
  return(approx)
  
}
composite.simpson(x^3/2,0,1,n)
```

Answer (score 0):

beside there is an unneeded `}`in your code (seems you cut it out of a function?),

the error for me only appeared for n<3. Which is correct.
xj is an vector with the length of n+1
Next two lines are shrinking your vector by 2. For n<3 this leads to a vector of length 1.
This leads to:

```
seq.int(from=2,to=1,by=2)
```

`to` < `from` & positive `by` --> error

**EDIT:**

Looking closer your code looks like the [simpson's rule](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/08/simpsons-rule-for-approximating-definite-integrals-in-r/) implementation.

```
n <- c(2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512)


f <- function(x) {
  return(x^3/2)
}

composite.simpson <- function(f, a, b, n) {
  h <- (b - a) / n
  xj <- seq.int(from = a, to = b, length.out = n + 1)
  xj <- xj[-1]
  xj <- xj[-length(xj)]
  approx <- (h / 3) * (f(a) + 
                         2 * sum(f(xj[seq.int(from = 2, to = length(xj), by = 2)])) + 
                         4 * sum(f(xj[seq.int(from = 1, to = length(xj), by = 2)])) + 
                         f(b))
  
  return(approx)
  } 

composite.simpson(f,0,1,n)
```

But still `n = 2` is not going to work. As the two lines:

```
  xj <- xj[-1]
  xj <- xj[-length(xj)]
```

will bring the length of xj to 1 and thereby

```
2 * sum(f(xj[seq.int(from = 2, to = length(xj), by = 2)])) +
```

this part becomes

```
2 * sum(f(xj[seq.int(from = 2 to = 1 , by = 2)]))+
```

which is not going to work,as `from > to` with positive by argument.

I also found some other implementations, which "directly" exclude n = 2 or switch to a different method ([example](https://github.com/moviedo5/fda.usc/blob/master/R/int.simpson.R) line 70).

Comment: i tried to edit on it but still give me the same issue , that i have done

Comment: y <- function(x) {
  return(x^3/2)
}
xn=1
x0=0
n <- c(2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512)
N<-as.numeric(n)
composite.simpson <- function(f, a, b, N) {
h <- (xn - x0) / N
xj <- seq.int(x0, xn, length.out = N + 1)
xj <- xj[-1]
xj <- xj[-length(xj)]
approx <- (h / 3) * (f(x0) + 2 * sum(f(xj[seq.int(2, length(xj), 2)])) + 4 * sum(f(xj[seq.int(1, length(xj), 2)])) + f(x0))
  
  return(approx)
  
}
composite.simpson(y,0,1,N)

Comment: your as.numeric(n) did not tackle the error with n=2. I edited my answer and tried to explain more in detail.